# How to redirect using tr onlick url action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have this Razor page named Userview which includes a list of students in a table

I want the code to work so that When I click on a row, it'll redirect to /Userview/Info?id. Here's what I got so far

```
    @foreach (var student in Model._User.Students)
    {
        <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Info", new { id = student.Id }))'">
            <td>Some basic info of student</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I instead got /Useview/{id}?action=Info. Can anyone help, thanks a lot.

Comment: may you post your routeconfig? `app.UseMvc(routes =>` maybe there is something configured differently than the standard.

Comment: Here's my routeconfig ```app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```
I was able to make it work using ```onclick= "window.location.href = '/Userview/Info?id=' + @Students.Id;"```, but I'd love to learn more.

Comment: What I get is  `/Useview/Info/{id}` instead of ` /Useview/{id}?action=Info`.Do you mean you would like to pass Id as query string instead of route data?

Comment: maybe we need to clarify: are you using .net core or classic mvc?